# Stale closures issues in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

I am revisiting closures, and I have stumbled over the following, which I can't really get my head around, could someone please help me with the following?

```
function Inc(){
  let v = 0
  let p = v
  
  function value() {
    console.log('p',p)
    console.log('v', v)
  }
  
  function setValue() {  
    v += 1;
    console.log(v)
  }
  
  return [value, setValue]
}

let [value, setValue] = Inc()

value() // p 0 , v 0
setValue() 
value() // p 0, v1
```

Based on my understanding, closures close over the primitive value they were created with. In this case shouldn't be the value of v be also 0? What happens in `setValue` body that somehow updates the value in `value`?

Thanks!

Comment: "_that somehow updates the value in `value`_" Nope, `v` is updated in `setValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Closures close over **variables**, not values.

- `v` is closed over.
- `setValue` changes `v`
- `value` reads `v`.

Comment: So is it safe to say that only closed over variables getting updated ?